# Как принимать пользовательские данные из QLineEdit после нажатия клавиши enter?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, qlineedit

Задача состоит в том, чтобы в поле `QLineEdit` принимать строку или число и сохранить ее в переменную после нажатия клавиши `enter`, искал в интернете, но там есть только ввод в консоль по нажатию кнопки, а мне необходимо , чтобы после `enter` данные записывались в переменную.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(639, 480)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(639, 480))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(639, 480))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lets_parse = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.lets_parse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 350, 341, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.lets_parse.setFont(font)
        self.lets_parse.setObjectName("lets_parse")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.sort_method = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.sort_method.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 80, 171, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.sort_method.setFont(font)
        self.sort_method.setObjectName("sort_method")
        self.sort_method.addItem("")
        self.sort_method.addItem("")
        self.sort_method.addItem("")
        self.sort_method.addItem("")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 40, 161, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.url_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.url_input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 49, 291, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.url_input.setFont(font)
        self.url_input.setObjectName("url_input")
        self.max_pages = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.max_pages.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 160, 311, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.max_pages.setFont(font)
        self.max_pages.setObjectName("max_pages")
        self.page_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.page_input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 180, 41, 21))
        self.page_input.setObjectName("page_input")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 170, 141, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 639, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.lets_parse.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cпарсить"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Url адресс:"))
        self.sort_method.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "без сортировки"))
        self.sort_method.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "дешевле"))
        self.sort_method.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "дороже"))
        self.sort_method.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "по дате"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Метод сортировки"))
        self.max_pages.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Максимальное количество страниц : "))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Количесиво страниц"))
    def url_redactor(self):
        print(self.url_input.text())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**НИКОГДА Не** изменяйте код, сгенерированный *Qt Designer*, **НИКОГДА**. 
Создайте другой класс,
который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

> void QLineEdit::**`editingFinished`**()
>
> Этот сигнал излучается при нажатии клавиши `Return` или `Enter` или `при потере фокуса` при редактировании строки. 
> Обратите внимание, что если в строке редактирования установлен `validator()`  или `inputMask()` и нажата клавиша enter/return, сигнал `editFinished()` будет выдан только в том случае, если ввод следует за `inputMask()` и `validator()`  возвращает `QValidator::Acceptable`.

или

> void QLineEdit::**`returnPressed`**()
>
> Этот сигнал излучается при нажатии клавиши `Return` или `Enter`. 
> Обратите внимание, что если в строке редактирования установлен `validator()`  или `inputMask()` и нажата клавиша enter/return, сигнал `editFinished()` будет выдан только в том случае, если ввод следует за `inputMask()` и `validator()`  возвращает `QValidator::Acceptable`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(639, 480)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(639, 480))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(639, 480))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lets_parse = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.lets_parse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 350, 341, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.lets_parse.setFont(font)
        self.lets_parse.setObjectName("lets_parse")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.sort_method = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.sort_method.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 80, 171, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.sort_method.setFont(font)
        self.sort_method.setObjectName("sort_method")
        self.sort_method.addItem("")
        self.sort_method.addItem("")
        self.sort_method.addItem("")
        self.sort_method.addItem("")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 40, 161, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.url_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.url_input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 49, 291, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.url_input.setFont(font)
        self.url_input.setObjectName("url_input")
        self.max_pages = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.max_pages.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 160, 311, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.max_pages.setFont(font)
        self.max_pages.setObjectName("max_pages")
        self.page_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.page_input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 180, 41, 21))
        self.page_input.setObjectName("page_input")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 170, 141, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 639, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.lets_parse.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cпарсить"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Url адресс:"))
        self.sort_method.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "без сортировки"))
        self.sort_method.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "дешевле"))
        self.sort_method.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "дороже"))
        self.sort_method.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "по дате"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Метод сортировки"))
        self.max_pages.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Максимальное количество страниц : "))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Количесиво страниц"))
        

class Window(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
# !!! тут ваша логика vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.url_input.editingFinished.connect(self.url_redactor)         # +++
        # или так 
        #self.url_input.returnPressed.connect(self.url_redactor)           # +++            

    def url_redactor(self):
        print(self.url_input.text())
       

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Появился еще мини вопрос: почему при вашем коде  после if __name__ == "__main__": все срабатывает, а в моем варианте нет?

Comment: @Bubunduc  НИКОГДА Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то один из вариантов:

UPD: Если ответа не находите на форумах, то лезьте в документацию: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html . В ней подробно описано про каждый виджет, сигналы этого виджета и тому подобное..

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.edit = QLineEdit(self)

        self.edit.returnPressed.connect(self.enter_checker)

    def enter_checker(self):
            self.userText = self.edit.text()
            self.edit.clear()
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```